# Необходимо вывести двумерный массив определенным образом (Лесенкой)

Tags: c#, .net

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Массив заполнен нулями и единицами. Вывести его таким образом: первая строка единицы, далее в каждой строке с конца появляется один ноль, потом два, потом
три и т.д.

Моя попытка (код):

```
int[,] a = new int[5, 5];
int zero = 0;   
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        a[i, j] = r.Next(0, 2);
        //Console.Write("{0,4}", a[i, j]);
        if (i == 0)
         {
          
          Console.Write("{0,4}", a[i, j]=1);
         }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
   { 
       if (i + j < 5){
           Console.Write(a[i, j] = 1);
       }else{
           Console.Write(a[i, j] = 0);
       }
   }
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

если i + j < 5 то пишем 1, иначе 0

Comment: это лишнее, условия в цикле вполне хватит (`for (int j = 0; j < 5-i; j++)`)

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Зачем тебе вообще рандом?

```
int[,] a = new int[5, 5];

...
// Запись единиц в нужные места
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j < 5-i; j++)
    {
        a[i, j] = 1;
    }
}
//Вывод массива как на фото
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(a[i, j] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: ну да можно и без него

Comment: Нужно без него. Вот тебе решение, второй цикл записывает в 1 строку сначала 5 единиц, потом 4, потом 3... это из-за ```j < 5-i```, проверь работу с помощью отладки кода.